# NGXS ofAction is not triggered inside of Angular resolver service

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am trying to implement a resolver which will first dispatch the action to retrieve all of the data from the server and then I try to capture two streams responseOK and responseError and then from the resolver return which ever stream emits value first. This set up is inspired by the following answer on github https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/270#issuecomment-317232654

here is my resolver:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class ScheduleAdministrationResolver
    implements Resolve<Observable<Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesSuccess | Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesFailed>> {
    constructor(private store: Store, private actions$: Actions, private router: Router) {}

    resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ):
        | Observable<Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesSuccess | Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesFailed>
        | Observable<Observable<Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesSuccess | Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesFailed>>
        | Promise<Observable<Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesSuccess | Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesFailed>> {
        this.store.dispatch(new Schedule.FetchAllSportTypes());

        const responseOK = this.actions$.pipe(ofAction(Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesSuccess));

        const responseError = this.actions$.pipe(
            ofAction(Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesFailed),
            tap(() => this.router.navigate([""]))
        );
        console.log("Inside SportType resolver");
        return race(responseOK, responseError).pipe(first());
    }
}
```

the `this.store.dispatch(new Schedule.FetchAllSportTypes());` method ends up calling `fetchAllSportTypes()` which looks like this:

```
fetchAllSportTypes(): Observable<SportType[]>{
 return of([{...}, {...}])
}
```

Everything works as expected and gets triggered as expected. However, the resolver never completes. It seems like the streams inside the `race` method never emit any values. I do know for sure that the `Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesSuccess` action gets dispatched as I log it the console when it gets triggered.

I do not understand why the `ofAction` is not triggered as expected.

Additional Info:
This is inside the admin feature that is lazy loaded. I wire up NGXS in the following way:

```js
app.module.ts;
imports: [
    ...NgxsModule.forFeature([SportTypeState]),
    NgxsModule.forRoot([], {
        developmentMode: true,
        selectorOptions: {
            suppressErrors: false,
            injectContainerState: false
        }
    })
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue. The problem was inside of my 'async' method that was fetching all of the `sportTypes`.

```
fetchAllSportTypes(): Observable<SportType[]>
{
   return of([{...}, {...}])
}
```

the above method did NOT work inside the resolver. Adding `.pipe(delay(1000))` ended up working as expected.

```
fetchAllSportTypes(): Observable<SportType[]>
{
   return of([{...}, {...}]).pipe(delay(1000))
}
```